# play music with html

Tags: html

my music is keept on desktop with this name

```
doli mix - arcax(Mus.Ge).mp3
```

how to write code to play this music in html?

Answer (score 7):

HTML is just a markup language. As such, it can't play music. In fact, it can't even *display* anything. All the rendering is done by the browser.

So what you want is to make the browser play music, and that can be done using the `<embed>` tag:

```
<embed src="yourfile.mp3" autostart=true loop=false volume=100 
hidden=true><noembed><bgsound src="yourfile.mp3"></noembed>
```

I strongly recommend not doing this though, since it's *extremely* annoying.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML 5 `audio` tag ([reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp)):

```
<audio src="yourfile.ogg" controls="controls">
```

Of course this won't work on older browsers.

Comment: @jan jongboom: Except in recent browsers like firefox, safari... and generally speaking recent layout engines like gecko, webkit and presto. but aside from that, it won't work _anywhere_ :\

Answer (score 0):

Even a simple anchor tag `<a href="file://yourfile">mp3</a>` will play this music if you have your browser set up with a plugin like VLC, QuickTime, Windows Media Player, etc. Click the link and it will take you to a new page with the media renderer.

Answer (score 0):

The code below would autoplay you music in the html document. All you need to do is put the music in the same folder as the html document. The autoplay loop part would make it automatically play the music and loop it together. You can remove these if you want to. Hope it is helpful.

```
<audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="doli mix - arcax(Mus.Ge).mp3 " type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```